# Show "last login" information when "su"

Tags: linux, pam

I'm trying to configure the PAM modules working with `su` command. I want to `su` shows the "last login" information, as `ssh` or `login` do.

I find, on `/etc/pam.d/login` a PAM module called `pam_lastlog` that does exactly what I want. I simply copy the line from `login` to  `su` configuration file, but when I run `su` I didn't get the expected behavior.

This is the content of my `/etc/pam.d/su`:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth     sufficient     pam_rootok.so
auth     include        common-auth
account  sufficient     pam_rootok.so
account  include        common-account
password include        common-password
session  include        common-session
session  optional   pam_lastlog.so  nowtmp
session  optional       pam_xauth.so
```

This is the default GNU/Linux distribution's file, only adding the `session  optional   pam_lastlog.so  nowtmp` line commented above.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured that changing the order on the session modules works:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth     sufficient     pam_rootok.so
auth     include        common-auth
account  sufficient     pam_rootok.so
account  include        common-account
password include        common-password
session  optional       pam_lastlog.so  nowtmp
session  include        common-session
session  optional       pam_xauth.so
```

Putting `pam_lastlog` just before the include of `common-session` just works. As you can read in my comment to @jeffatrackaid, I still don't understand why the order influences in that way.

The `common-session` included file has the following 3 modules:

```
session  required      pam_limits.so
session  required      pam_unix2.so
session  optional      pam_umask.so
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your line to:

session  required  pam_lastlog.so nowtmp

```
    $ su 
Password: 
Last login: Thu May 30 16:19:42 EDT 2013 on pts/0
```

Works on RHEL/CentOS 6 box.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer jeffattrackaid, but it is still not working on the distro I'm testing. I just tested on another distro (Debian) and it works using `session optional` too! Is there any way to "debug" de PAM API and check what is happening?

Comment: I just discover my mistake: I was writing the config line **after** the `include common-session`. Now, I just put it before this line and it works. I still cannot understand why is this happening. My `common-session` file has the following modules: pam_limits (required), pam_unix2 (required) and pam_umask (optional).